# Safari and duplicate property display

Tags: safari, postcss, autoprefixer

I'm using `gulp` with `postcss/autoprefixer` and have the `browserlists` list set up as a .browserslistrc file and that's all working well but when it comes to Safari and using flexbox I'm still getting this issue...

[image]

Safari then completely ignores flexbox as it seems to have an issue with the display duplication. I have the browserslist query set as `Last 2 versions`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue myself, ended up playing around and figured out if you put the css properties in the correct order it seems to solve the problem:

```
display: flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
```